# Is a 1x6 enough to secure a wall mount sink?

Tags: framing, sink

I'm doing a mild bathroom remodel and plan to install a wall mount sink since it's a small half bath and that would open the room up. I had originally planned to install a 2x6 between two wall studs to mount the sink too. Unfortunately it turns out the hot water supply line to the entire house comes into this wall, and the drain vent goes right behind it too, so I only have enough clearance to fit a 1x6 in there instead.

Would a 1x6 secured with screws and liquid nails be sturdy enough to support a wall mount sink? The sink itself weighs around 40lbs but I figure at some point someone will lean on it so it's got to be secured pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something wider than a 1x6 - why not?  Even if the mounting plate is smaller, the wider board will be easier to hit, and will be stronger.

If yellow pine or douglas fir are available they are a lot stronger than white pine.

I don't trust toe-nail attachments with skinny boards.  The old school way to do it would to be notch the studs so the board lays in the notch, then face nail (or better, face screw) it into the studs. 
 But that's a bit of work, not too bad with an oscillating tool but still.

The easier alternative would be to use an angle bracket.  For example, the Simpson Strong Tie L70Z is not made for this exact purpose, but I think it would be suitable, and it would be easy to make a very strong attachment.

[image]

Comment: Well I can't use a wider board because the piping in the wall only gives me 3/4 of clerance. And I've got the whole wall open to repair a pipe in there so I don't have to tonail, I planned to use screws from the other side of the stud. But the angle bracket is a good idea too.

Comment: I see, screwing that way will be stronger than toe nailing.  The angle bracket or let-in notch would still be stronger though.  Regarding using a wider board - I didn't mean like a 2x6 - that's what I'd call thicker - I meant like a 1x10 or a 1x12, that just gives you 10" instead of 6" to attach to the stud.

Answer (score 1):

A 1x6 will work and I have seen plenty done this way especially older homes. You have to consider that on top of the 1x6 will be green board or cement backer board depending on the finish and possibly tile, all that will add strength. I have also seen marine plywood used as a support. 
By the way that's a mighty heavy bathroom sink even if it was cast iron.